# make the first div not push the next

Tags: html, css, image, text, alignment

How can I make the first div (containing the text) not push the images?
As in the second, if the text is longer, it pushes my image to the right.

I mention that the div with text is floated left and has some left and right padding.

Also, I cannot float the images right.

[this is what i mean](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UKFpy.png)

Any ideas?

This is the code:

```css
.text box {
  float: left;
  padding-right: 100px;
  padding-left: 100px;
}

div#firstimagediv,
div#secondimagediv {
  width: 657px;
  height: 225px;
  max-width: 100%;
  max-height: 100%;
  overflow: hidden;
  margin-left: 50px;
}

div#firstimagediv figure {
  background-image: url(https://placeholder.pics/svg/200.jpg);
  background-size: cover;
  position: relative;
  font-size: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
}

div#secondimagediv figure {
  background-image: url(https://placeholder.pics/svg/200.jpg);
  background-size: cover;
  position: relative;
  font-size: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="text box">
  <h1>Text</h1>
  <p>ParagraphParagraphParagraphParagraph</p>
  <p>Paragraph</p>
  <p>Paragraph</p>
  <p>Paragraph</p>
  <p>Paragraph</p>
</div>
<div id="firstimagediv">
  <figure>
    <div id="firstimage"></div>
  </figure>
</div>

<div class="text box">
  <h1>Longer Text</h1>
  <p>ParagraphParagraphParagraphParagraph</p>
  <p>Paragraph</p>
  <p>Paragraph</p>
  <p>Paragraph</p>
  <p>Paragraph</p>
</div>
<div id="secondimagediv">
  <figure>
    <div id="secondimage"></div>
  </figure>
</div>
```

Comment: Post your code so that we will get the idea what you have done wrong?

Comment: @Debabrata ...it's added, thanks

Comment: So basically you want to wrap the text inside the div?I mean if a long line comes then you want to break into multiple lines

Comment: @Adrian thank you for the edit, using [this](https://placeholder.com/) as a resource for dummy images may help to further illustrate your problem.

Comment: You'll need to define a width or max-width property for your left floated div to prevent it from pushing the other divs. You aren't currently setting any constraints on its maximum size, so it will simply continue to grow.

Comment: Thanks @JDDavis but setting the width didn't fix it.

Comment: you're right @Debabrata, I want to break the line, and not push the image, as the images should stay all on the same horizontal line.

Comment: @Adrian you want this only for thr first div?

Comment: For all divs, I will have many of them, and images should stay on the right, aligned.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check the below snippet and tell me if this is what you want or i will edit my answer according to your need.(click on the option expand snippet to view clearly).First what you were doing wrong was making a class name like `text box` having space in between.That is counted as two classes.To  wrap the texts around i used css `word-wrap` property and did some minor corrections.So check if this satisfies your need.

```css
.textbox {
   padding-left:100px;
  float: left;
  max-width:30%;
  word-wrap:break-word;
  padding-right: 100px;
}

div#firstimagediv, div#secondimagediv { 
  max-width: 70%;
  height: 100%;
  overflow: hidden;
  /*margin-left: 50px;*/
}
img{
height:inherit;
width:inherit
}
```

```html
<div>
<div class="textbox">
  <h1>Text</h1>
  <p>ParagraphParagraphParagraphParagraphpppppppppppppppppppppppppppppppppppppppppppppppppppppppppppppppppppppppppppppppppppppppppppppppppppppppppp</p>
  <p>Paragraph</p>
  <p>Paragraph</p>
  <p>Paragraph</p>
  <p>Paragraph</p>
</div>
 <div id="firstimagediv">
  <figure>
    <div id="firstimage">
     <img src="http://via.placeholder.com/700x300" />
    </div>
  </figure>
</div>
</div>

<div>
<div class="textbox">
  <h1>Longer Text</h1>
  <p>ParagraphParagraphParagraphParagraphppppppppppppppppppppppppppppppppppppppppppppppppppppppppppppppppppppppppppppppp</p>
  <p>Paragraph</p>
  <p>Paragraph</p>
  <p>Paragraph</p>
  <p>Paragraph</p>
</div>
 <div id="secondimagediv">
  <figure>
    <div id="secondimage">
    <img src="http://via.placeholder.com/700x300" />
    </div>
  </figure>
</div>
</div>
```

Comment: That's exactely what I'm looking for. Thanks so much. I'm just having problems implementing it now. maybe it's because I have some conflicting style for the figure?